# Self join gives wrong output

Tags: sql

Consider the following table :

```
id  |  Name  | City
1   |  Roger | Atlanta
2   |  Roger | Atlanta
3   |  Roger | Miami
4   |  Roger | Miami
```

Now what I want is if I enter as an input the id 1, the output should be id 2 (the other one that is in the same City). I've tried making a self join on the 'City' column, but it's not working.

Comment: show as the statement you wrote and what it's result is (or the error you are getting)

Comment: Please elaborate on the input/output part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this work correctly?

```
SELECT t2.id FROM MyTable t1
JOIN MyTable t2 ON (t1.City = t2.City AND t1.id <> t2.id)
WHERE t1.id = @input
```

Answer (score 0):

It willbe faster to avoid a join anyways and use something like:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `City` IN 
  (SELECT `City` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 1)
```

You might also want to check that name matches though (in which case it would probably be better to use a join). I'm not sure since you didn't say if that was a requirement, I just assumed it's not.

Comment: if this or one of the other solutions is faster depends on dozens of parameters, non of which is know to use. And it doesn't solve the problem (prints 1 and 2 instead of only 1). Typical case of premature optimization.

Comment: @Jens This will always be faster no matter what his indices are, his column types, or what engine he's using, because it is a join on a single column on the same table with itself there are a lot less parameters than you think, and I think he can easily remove the 1 from this if he wants to, he didn't say whether or not he wanted the 1 back, just that he wanted the 2.

Comment: I'm curious how you come to that conclusion, given that the engines are numerous as well as there optimizing strategies (of which many details are secret)

Comment: Quote: "the output should be id 2"

Comment: This won't work since it will return me id 1 and 2. And no, the name doesn't need to match.